# Why get params are crashing my redirects in my authorize helper?

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, get

I'm using a helper to authorize the access to admin pages.

The problem is when try access paths with 2 or more params.

Exemples: 
- when I try to access /admin it redirects to /admin/login (OK)
- when I try to access /admin/ it redirects to /admin/admin/login (BAD)
- when I try to access /admin/users it redirects to /admin/admin/login (BAD)
- when I try to access /admin/users/add it redirects to /admin/users/admin/login (VERY BAD)

```
    module.exports = {
        authorizeAll: function(req,res,next){
            /*
                nivel
                if (req.isAuthenticated() && req.user.nivel >= 1){
            */
            if (req.isAuthenticated()){
                return next()
            }
            req.flash("error_msg", "Você precisa estar logado para ter acesso!");
            res.redirect('admin/login');
        }

}
```

what can i do to use a "base" url to redirect?
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding `/` in front of `admin/login`. Express routing is looking relative to the route that you are hitting when it is set up with `admin/login`. Adding `/` should make it look from the root.

```
 module.exports = {
    authorizeAll: function(req,res,next){
        /*
            nivel
            if (req.isAuthenticated() && req.user.nivel >= 1){
        */
        if (req.isAuthenticated()){
            return next()
        }
        req.flash("error_msg", "Você precisa estar logado para ter acesso!");
        res.redirect('/admin/login'); // Only this line should change
    }
}
```